# Unable to assign data frame value to variable (only when ran in script) - VERY STRANGE

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc

I'm pulling a table from SQL Server in R, and I cannot assign some of the table values to variables as part of a script, even though they are 100% valid column names with actual values.

For example, if I run this script,

```
library(odbc)

# SQL Server credentials
Driver = "SQL Server"
Server= "*******"
Database = "******"

Connection = dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       .connection_string = paste("driver={", Driver,
                                                  "};server=", Server,
                                                  ";database=", Database,
                                                  ";trusted_connection=true",
                                                  sep = "")
)

# The data pull - Works perfectly (1 Row, 600 Columns)
dataPull = dbGetQuery(Connection,
                      paste0("SELECT ",
                             "* ",
                             "FROM ",
                             "Some Location")
                      ))

# Assign one of the column values to variable x
x = dataPull$`C&R RE 1–4 Family Residential`

# Print the value to the console (returns NULL when the value should be 0)
print(x)

# Shown in console
NULL
```

The output to the console is NULL when it should be the value zero. If, however, I run the same script above and then proceed to copy and run the last couple of lines directly in the console, I get the correct value of zero

```
# Run directly in the console after running the initial script - It works
x = dataPull$`C&R RE 1–4 Family Residential`
print(x)
[1] 0
```

This only seems to occur with a few variables that contain dashes and ampersands...

I've been programming in R for fives years, and I cannot seem to find an explanation anywhere. So, thanks in advance to any rock stars who can shed some light on this matter!!

Comment: Do you get the same results if yopu put the column names in regular quotes rather than backticks? Backticks are sometimes parsed as language elements which would result in the minus signs and ampersands being interpreted as infix operators.

Comment: What happens if you access it using `dataPull[["C&R RE 1–4 Family Residential"]]` (assuming `dataPull` is a list)?

Comment: @42, When I use regular quotes, I get the same result, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @tobiasegli_te, I'm working with a data frame, which is the default class of data pulled from SQL Server via dbGetQuery. For the sake of giving your suggestion a shot, I converted the data frame to a list, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I could come up with was re-rendering the data frame as follows,

```
# This converts the names to acceptable values 
dataPull = data.frame(dataPull, check.names = TRUE)
print(dataPull[,"C.R.RE.1.4.Family.Residential"])

[1] 0
```

So, it seems like something was going on with the dashes and ampersands that R did not like. Either way, the script is running fine now.

I hope this is helpful for anyone else who might run into this...

Cheers,